# differential inequality implies continuity

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $f$ is continuously differentiable over $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ with $f'(x)\geq 0,\forall x \in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ and $f(0)=0$. Is the following statement valid?

$(f^2)'\leq \frac{2}{x}f^2, \forall x\in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ if and only if $\frac{f^2}{x^2}$ is right-continuous at $0$.

If yes, prove it; otherwise provide a counter-example.

My approach: The condition $(f^2)'\leq \frac{2}{x}f^2$ implies that $f'\leq \frac{f}{x}$, which is pertinent to Gronwall's inequality, but this does not seem to guarentee $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f^2}{x^2}$ exist. However it is not obvious that how this direction may be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: $f(x) = e^{-1/x}, x > 0,$ $f(0)=0.$